# Why do Every time I start my function I get NaN

Tags: javascript

I just wanna ask you why do I get NaN when I start my function?

```
  var hasan = {
    hasfriend : true,
    speaking : 8,
    reading : 7,
    listening : 7.5,
    writing : 8.5,
    job : "Dentistry",
    education : "Master",
    yearsofExperience : 8,
  }
  var ahmad = {
    hasfriend : false,
    speaking : 7,
    reading : 8,
    listening : 7.5,
    writing : 6.5,
    job : "Web developer",
    education : "Bach",
    yearsofExperience : 6,
  }
  var zen = {
    hasfriend : true,
    speaking : 9,
    reading : 8,
    listening : 7.5,
    writing : 5.5,
    job : "Medicine",
    education : "PhD",
    yearsofExperience : 3,
  }
  function relatives(applicant) {
    var hasfriend;
    if (hasfriend !== false) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  function ieltsCalculator(applicant) {
    var speaking, reading, listening, writing;
    var band = speaking + reading + listening + writing / 4
    var bandNumber = Number(band);
  return bandNumber;
  console.log(bandNumber);
  }
  function crsCalculator(applicant) {
    var education, yearsofExperience, joblist, job, points;
    joblist = ["Dentistry", "Medicine", "Engingering", "Nursing"];
    if (education = "Phd") {
      points += 200
    }
    else if (educatin = "Master") {
      points += 100
    }
    else {
      poins += 50
    }
    if (yearsofExperience >= 10) {
      points += 150
    }
    else if (yearsofExperience < 10 && yearsofExperience > 5) {
      points += 100
    }
    else if (yearsofExperience >= 3 && yearsofExperience <= 5) {
      points += 50
    }
    else {
      points += 0
    }
    if (joblist.includes(job) === true ) {
      points += 150
    }
    else {
      points += 0
    }
    return points;
  };
  function canadaVisa(applicant) {
    var crs, ielts, hasrelative;
     crs = crsCalculator(applicant)
     ielts = ieltsCalculator(applicant)
     hasrelative = relatives(applicant)
    if ( crs >= 400 && ielts > 7 && hasrelative == true ) {
      console.log(applicant + " will get the visa");
    }
  }
```

I tried to change some variables into integers but nothing changed.
thank you in advance.

Comment: You could have used those extra words to identify **which one of the four functions in this code** causes the problem for you.

Comment: Please add some related words too, like which of those four functions gives you NaN, and what you expect to get instead, and where and how are you calling it?

Comment: Without too many words, the variable handling in the functions seem a bit odd. E.g. in `ieltsCalculator` you're declaring some variables, then make some math with them, but never assign any values to those variables. That way it is very easy to get `NaN` as a result. Are you expecting those variables being somehow connected to the properties in the above-created objects?

Comment: Thank you guys for your helpful comments, I have noticed that I didn't assign any value to the variables in the `ieltsCalculator`.

Comment: There it is again, a declared variable without an assigned value, see here --> `var joblist, points;`. Without the assigned value `points` is `undefined` when you do `points += 200`, you get the first `NaN`, and that wont wear away later, no matter how many times you would add a number to `NaN`...

Comment: @Teemu yes you're right. I missed again. thank you so much my friend. please pardon me, but I'm kinda new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually use the `applicant` object in your functions.

Example:

```
  function ieltsCalculator(applicant) {
    var speaking, reading, listening, writing;
    var band = speaking + reading + listening + writing / 4
    var bandNumber = Number(band);
    return bandNumber;
    console.log(bandNumber);
  }
```

What this code calculates an average of is four `undefined` values. All you've done is created variables but none of them have values assigned.

It appears your intent is to create a variable named `band` that is assigned a value that is the average of speaking, reading, listening and writing **from the applicant**.

To do that you need to change your code thus:

```
  function ieltsCalculator(applicant) {
    var band = applicant.speaking + applicant.reading + applicant.listening + applicant.writing / 4
    return band;
  }
```

You will need to follow this pattern in all four functions for them to work the way you expect.